# select item from dropdown

Tags: vb.net

How can I if there is a drop box in a webbrowser and it has either male or female it will auto select male?

i tried this

```
 WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gender").SetAttribute("value", "Male")
```

but didn't work

Use VB.net

Comment: Dont use language names in your titles please.  That is what tags are for.

Comment: It would also be helpful to tag the technology(Winforms,WPF,..) used. I assume Winforms.

Comment: I did in the tags... it Says VB.net.. I will add it to my post.

Comment: @user1284791: But you also prefixed the title ;) http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119406/147438 VB.NET will automatically be prefixed to the title(f.e. for search engines).

Comment: vb.net is a language.  Winforms, WPF, etc are platforms that you can target with a language.

Answer (score 1):

So what you will need to do is grab the dropdown box (Using `Document.GetElementById`), then find the item (`option` element), then set its selected attribute to true.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860511/get-a-listboxs-selected-items-in-javascript) may be of use to you.

Comment: @user1284791: But this still uses DOM, so the answer may be valid. Dont confuse Java script with HTML DOM.